# Creating a Web Worker in React always gives an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I am having the problem where every time i try to create a web worker returns the following error:

```
worker.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at worker.js:1:1)
```

Here is the simple worker i am trying to create:
worker.js

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    let message = e.data;
    console.log('Main thread said', message);
    postMessage('Hi!')
  }
```

App.js
...

```
  let worker = new Worker('worker.js')
  worker.postMessage('Hey!')
   
  worker.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log('Worker thread says', e.data)
  }
```

...

Comment: Are you sure the worker source code loads correctly? `<` is most likely the begin of a tag in an html error page of your web server. Check the devtools for details, and the file that was actually loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put your `worker.js` file inside the `public` folder, then your WebWorker may be loaded properly.

```
const worker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

Comment: you are my saviour